# Restart MySQL server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, database

I am using **MySQL v5.1** on **Ubuntu** machine.

MySQL on my machine used to work. (Running `mysql -u root` gave me the MySQL command line.)

This afternoon, I did the following thing:

**1.** check active process related to '`mysql`' by run:

```
$ ps aux | grep 'mysql'
mysql  1457  3.3  1.3 130044 27076 ?        Ssl  16:22   0:43 /usr/sbin/mysql
```

**2.** I saw from above output the PID of the mysql process is 1457, so I killed it with:

```
$ sudo kill 1457
```

**3.** now, if I run `$ mysql -u root` , I get an error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

which is reasonable since I killed the process.

How can I have my MySQL server back up and running again after I killed it?

I tried to run `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`, but my MySQL server does not start. Why is that?

Comment: The server process is mysql**d**. If it doesn't restart, you'll need to check the logs (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-logs.html) to see why it isn't starting. Can't help you without more information. BTW, killing database processes is a **Bad Idea**.

Comment: relate to your last line: what is the error message when you are try to start the server ?

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu you should use `service`:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

And in the future if and when you want to restart it:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=804021&page=3). You are using Ubuntu, so go to `System -> Administration -> Services` , uncheck MySQL, save it, and recheck it again.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably corrupted a database to the point mysqld won't start. Consult /var/log/daemon.log for mysql startup errors. Also look for /var/log/mysql.err and see if there is anything there.

In the future **"Don't Do That"** as unclean database server shutdown will corrupt myisam tables pretty badly and if you're lucky on innodb, just cause a major rollback that wipes all unssuccessful transactions.

You can find error message information on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/

Answer (score 0):

I would use daemontools or such to keep mysql running on the system incase of undesired shutdown of the database servers. However, as everyone else noted here, killing of database servers is really a bad idea in the production environment.

To answer the question of mysql would not start, its because mysql init script checks for the pidfile of the mysqld, I am not sure if it checks for the validity of the pid, and then the stalelock might be stopping mysql to start. Best is to do `service mysql restart` or `/etc/init.d/mysql restart` to ensure mysql is starting from base.
Ensure that mysql service is running with `ps` and `service mysqld status`
Also check the logs of mysqld, to check whether there was a clean startup of the process and all the databases/tables were properly initialized.